# Changing data type to a factor with pipe and it's not working

Tags: r, pipe

Just getting started with R.

I am trying to change season data type to factor and recode it to the appropriate season. However I get an error `f` must be a factor (or character vector)

```
bikedf%>%
      mutate(season = as.factor(season))%>%
      fct_recode("Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", 
      "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4")
```

However, it works when I don't use the pipe with it.

```
bikedf$season = as.factor(bikedf$season)%>%
  fct_recode("Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4")
```

I don't quite understand why isn't working with my first code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with R, I would suggest learning the base syntax before moving on to packaged syntax.

Answer (score 5):

The `%>%` should be within the `mutate` and not after closing the `)`

```
bikedf%>%
  mutate(season = as.factor(season)%>%
                   fct_recode("Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", 
                      "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4"))
```

Comment: I would have expected an automatic coercion to factor by a function named fct_recode.

Comment: @42- I think you're right. `fct_recode` will actually do the coercion. The `as.factor()` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you go with the original code you need to make sure to specify what variable (season) you want to `fct_recode()`:

```
bikedf%>%
      mutate(season = as.factor(season))%>%
      fct_recode(season, "Spring" = "1", "Summer" = "2", 
      "Fall" = "3", "Winter" = "4")
```